# Scapy will listen on wlan0 but not wlan1 that is set to monitor mode

Tags: python, network-programming, scapy

I have two wireless interfaces, `wlan0` and `wlan1`. I am connected to a raspberry pi on my home network via `wlan0` and I am using `wlan1` as an access point to collect probe requests.

I set `wlan1` into monitor mode (iwconfig shows mode: Master when changed)

```
subprocess.run(f'ifconfig wlan{interface_id} down', shell=True)
subprocess.run(f'ifconfig wlan{interface_id} mode Monitor', shell=True)
subprocess.run(f'ifconfig wlan{interface_id} up', shell=True)
```

When running this code to check the card is in monitor (Master) mode it returns true:

```
def is_card_in_mon_mode(interface_id):
    output = subprocess.Popen(['iwconfig', f'wlan{interface_id}'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for param in output.stdout:
        if b'Master' in param:
            return True
```

Then, performing: `sniff(iface="wlan1", prn=handle_packet)` doesn't access the handle_packet method.

Using `sniff(iface="wlan0", prn=handle_packet)` does access the `handle_packet` method, is there any reason it will work on wlan0 but not wlan1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm being dumb. There was no network traffic hence no call back function. Code above works as intended, if anyone else has this issue consider sending packets over that interface and then seeing if anything happens..